# Open a pop up that states that the sessions has expired and redirect the user to the default login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the solution of following problem in asp.net:

1. Open a pop up that states that the sessions has expired and redirect the user to the default login page.

OR

1. open a pop up that states that the sessions has expired, prompt for user credentials and after successfully authenticating, redirect the user to the page they were originally requesting to view. If authentication is not successful after three tries, redirect them to the default login page with a message stating that they were not authenticated.
   Additionally, how should i extend the existing time out values of session to accommodate lengthy queries?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a heartbeat AJAX call to the server (make sure that it doesn't use the session) every 30secs or so.